# google geocode not working for addresses with special characters from database

Tags: php, mysql, json, geocoding

I'm having an issue with special characters for addresses from my database for google geocode, but not if I hardcode them.

Simple geocode code

```
$url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=". $address . "&sensor=true";      
$jsonfile = file_get_contents($url);
$jsondata = json_decode($jsonfile);
$lat = $jsondata->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
$lng = $jsondata->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
```

This code works for standard addresses but doesn't work when the address has a special character in it IF it comes from my database.

If I hardcode the address as:

```
$address = "10 Montée de Clausen, 1343 Luxemburg City, Luxembourg";
$address = str_replace(" ","+",$address);
```

The code works.
If the address comes from my database

```
$query="SELECT * FROM mytable";
$result=mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], $query);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $address = $row['address'];
    $address = str_replace(" ","+",$address);
    // geocode code.
}
```

It doesn't work.

Database is in utf8_unicode_ci.
If I echo the $url including the address even if it has come from my database, and then put that url into a browser the url actually spits out the right data but using that url in my code doesn't work.

I've tried to url encode the address before the str_replace and also after the str_replace and it still doesn't work.

How do I get it to work?

Comment: What's the character encoding of the table?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if, you do the following:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM mytable";
$result=mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], $query);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $address = urlencode(mb_convert_encoding($row['address'], 'UTF-8'));
    // geocode code...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I thought it had something to do with the encoding but had no idea how to fix it.  Again, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try `urlencode` for database output data

Like

```
 $address = urlencode($row['address'])
```

Also remove this `$address = str_replace(" ","+",$address);` from current code.