# Google's geocoder not encoding special characters

Tags: html, asp.net, google-maps, character-encoding, geocoding

I am developing a geocoder using Google's geocoder API, and I am having difficulties passing an address with special characters into my personal geodatabase (.mdb)

Here is the original address:

> 96 Rue Gâtineau, 17150 Saint-Georges-des-Agoûts, France

And here is what gets inserted into my geodatabse:

> [image: encoding error in database, see image]

I have tried setting the charset in my .HTML file to "ISO-8859-15" as I mainly need English and French characters encoded.

I also changed the charset in my .ASP file to "<%Response.Charset="ISO-8859-15"%>", but neither of these seem to help with the special characters.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you don't use UTF-8?

A lot of database are in UTF-8

Comment: I believe that's what I had before and it did not work. I just confirmed that my database is in UTF-8, but that won't classify special characters for me as the result is the same as above

Comment: How you seen this post -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18912959/google-geocode-not-working-for-addresses-with-special-characters-from-database ?

Comment: I just looked at that post, thank you for that. But when I changed my .asp file to "var addy = Server.URLEncode(Request.Form("addy"));" which is what gets pushed into my database, this is the result:
"G%C3%A2tineau%2C37330%2CFrance"
And still just a bunch of jibberish, but it's a result. Any advice to get from this stage to real letters again?

Comment: Bonjour,je parlais en anglais sans même savoir que vous êtes français ,vraiment désolé,donc pour la variable il faut faire une urldecode (regardez ici ce qu'est urlencode http://www.url-encode-decode.com/)  et l'utilisation en javascript http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp PS: n'oubliez pas de fermer la question si elle est résolue

Comment: Awesome! That seems to have worked! Thank you very much for your help, even though I don't speak french but thank you for the consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look also at the default encoding in your database. In my experience, the encoding needs to match throughout.

Comment: I just checked my database and it states that it is in "UTF8", and advice on how to change the 'Metadata Character Set' of a personal file geodatabase table?